# jquery issue on click all modal window opens instead of each one

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm having an issue. I'm trying to activate a lightbox on click but its opening all the modal windows and not each one individually.

I was thinking of using `data-id` by having wordpress output the posts/page id/# but im not sure how to have that trigger/work with jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
$(".portfolio-item a[data-toggle='modal']").on("click", function(){ 
             console.log('click');
             $(".modal").modal();

           });
```

**Click**

```
   <a href="#myModal" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-toggle="modal"  >

                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

            </a>
 <a href="#myModal" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-toggle="modal"  >

                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

            </a>
```

**The modal windows**

```
 <div class="modal-portfolio modal " id="modal" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
          <div class="container">
            content box

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="modal-portfolio modal " id="modal" data-id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
          <div class="container">
            content box 2

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id must be unique so instead of adding same id in the content div you need to add the id that is returned from server and then utitilize the anchor tag `data-id` for the divs that need to be shown:

```
<div class="modal-portfolio modal " id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
          <div class="container">
            content box

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

 <div class="modal-portfolio modal " id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-close" data-dismiss="modal"></div>
          <div class="container">
            content box 2

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and then in jquery:

```
$(".portfolio-item a[data-toggle='modal']").on("click", function(){ 
  $("#"+$(this).data('id')).modal();
});
```

### EXPLANATION:

`this` referes to the object that is used in methods to refer to the object on which a method is being invoked.

### Reference Links:

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

[**What is this**](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/what-is-this/)

[**this and $(this) in Jquery Callbacks**](http://coding.abel.nu/2013/04/this-and-this-in-jquery-callbacks/)

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you link me up on a good reference to learn more about how to use `this` ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be using unique ID's. You should also be using jQuery(this) to find your data ID and call modal() from within your click function.

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Comment: Not sure why my answer was downvoted since I was basically saying the same thing. I could update my answer to describe in more detail.